# when i run pig command in linux getting some jdk error?

Tags: java, linux, apache-pig

I am running pig using cloudera on 5 vms. 
When I execute the pig command in 1st and 2nd vm it gives me pig grunt shell.

But when I tried to execute same **pig** command in third vm I am getting following error.

```
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 139: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/java: Success
```

please suggest something.

Comment: what is the output when you issue the java command on the command line, also what vm are you using?

Comment: It ends int the word `Success`. Are you sure this is an error and not just debug output?

Comment: Thats what it sounds like, this is not an error. Sounds more like output from whatever the command is doing.